# Stably computing large quantites through recursion

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-stability

I have two quantities a & b that are defined by recursion and through reference to another list of values x = [ x_1, x_2, ... x_N ], which will be an input to the program. The program will iterate over all the values in x and update a & b according to:

```
for n in range(1,N)
    a[n] = a[n-1] * exp(+x[n]) + b[n-1] * exp(-x[n])  
    b[n] = b[n-1] * exp(+x[n]) + a[n-1] * exp(-x[n])
```

and starting values

```
a[0] = exp(+x[0])
b[0] = exp(-x[0])
```

The values in x are not big numbers (always <10) but N will be in the hundreds, and because of all the exponentials the final values of a & b will be very large. I'm worried that because of the form of the recursion where we are constantly multiplying exponentially large numbers with exponentially small ones and adding them this scheme will become quite numerically unstable.

Ideally I would calculate log(a) and log(b) instead to stop the values becoming too large. But because of the recursion scheme that's not possible, unless I compute something much messier like

```
log_a[n] = x[n] + log_a[n-1] + log( 1 + exp(-2*x[n] + log_b[n-1]-log_a[n-1] ) )
```

Is numerical stability something I am right to be concerned about here? And if so would something like the log based scheme help to stabilise it?

Comment: Your messier expression can be improved by using `log1p(x) == log(1+x)`, which is more numerically stable

Comment: I'm assuming your starting values use `x[0]`, and not `x[n]`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It should be x[0] in the starting conditions. Thanks for the tip about log1p too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite that first as:

```
for n in range(1,N)
    a[n] = exp(log(a[n-1]) + x[n]) + exp(log(b[n-1]) - x[n])
    b[n] = exp(log(b[n-1]) + x[n]) + exp(log(a[n-1]) - x[n]))
```

Then change our iteration variables:

```
for n in range(1,N)
    log_a[n] = log(exp(log_a[n-1] + x[n]) + exp(log_b[n-1] - x[n]))
    log_b[n] = log(exp(log_b[n-1] + x[n]) + exp(log_a[n-1] - x[n]))
```

Which can be computed more stably using `np.logaddexp`:

```
for n in range(1,N)
    log_a[n] = np.logaddexp(log_a[n-1] + x[n], log_b[n-1] - x[n])
    log_b[n] = np.logaddexp(log_b[n-1] + x[n], log_a[n-1] - x[n])
```

The implementation of `logaddexp` can be seen [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/fd1d7deb1b8bd23ba59f2486c362125c17875946/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c.src#L569-L588)

Comment: This is great, thanks! Are there any disadvantages at all to using logaddexp, and do you think numerical stability would have been a problem with the original code?

Comment: @RGWinston: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to either of those questions.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware, all(?) recursive problems can be solved through dynamic programming. For example, the Fibonacci sequence could be expressed like so:

```
def fibo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

Or, iteratively:

```
n = 10
fibo_nums = [0, 1]
while len(fibo_nums) <= n:
    fibo_nums.append(fibo_nums[-2] + fibo_nums[-1])
```

Presumably if you have a recursive problem you could perform a similar unpacking.

Comment: The OP has already performed such an unpacking. The formula itself is "recursive", but the code in the question is not

Comment: @Eric ah. I didn't see any recursion in the OP's code, and am unfamiliar with the problem domain. And since the question title talks about recursion I assumed there was something happening elsewhere in their code.